# Compute the limit of $ \lim_{n \uparrow \infty} [f(x)e^{nx} + g(x)]/(e^{xn}+1)$, with $ x>0$ and $g(x)$ bounded

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

- List item

> Compute the limit
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(x)e^{nx}+g(x)}{e^{nx}+1},$$
>
> where $x>0$ and $g$ is bounded.

Got no clue on this. A book claims f(x) as its limit without any hints and the only I see that could happen is when f=g. But I guess that doesn't work!

Comment: Please try and use LaTeX/MathJax to properly write the expression in the limit.

Comment: I have rewritten the expression in LaTeX

Comment: I have edited the expressioninto the body of the question, please check if it is correct and try to write out the question in the body (not just the title) in the future.

Comment: Yes it is correct. I will follow that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Rewrite the expression in the limit as

$$\frac{f(x)e^{nx}}{e^{nx}+1}+\frac{g(x)}{e^{nx}+1}=\frac{f(x)}{1+\frac{1}{e^{nx}}}+\frac{g(x)}{e^{nx}+1}$$

Can you compute the limit of each term in the sum above?

Comment: Limit of first term is f(x). My question is why the limit of second term is 0? Is there any property of bounded function regarding this?

Comment: Yes. Since $g$ is bounded there is some $M>0$ with $|g(x)|<M$ for all $x$. Then:

$$0\leq \left|\frac{g(x)}{e^{nx}+1}\right|\leq \left|\frac{M}{e^{nx}+1}\right|$$

Now, apply the [squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem). The same method shows more generally that in the produt of a bounded term by a term that approaches $0$, the product itself must approach $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Simply $g(x) $ is bounded finitely. Thus:
$$\frac{f(x)+\frac{g(x)}{e^{nx}}}{1+\frac{1}{e^{nx}}}$$

as $n\to\infty$, $e^{nx}\to\infty$
Thus it leaves you with $f(x)$

Comment: Thanks man. The way you have written the expression, the information g is bounded is necessary?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise how would we compute if $g\to \infty$. That would've been a different case altogether @AnuranChowdhury